# Memorystream to CSV (open in Excel) column header widths for modifying exponential number format display

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, asp.net-4.5

The main reason why I want to do the following is to display a large number not in exponential format in Excel.  If there is a better way than modifying the column width headers without modifying the current structure/method, but just adding or slightly modifying the following code, then please let me know.  Thanks.

The following is the code that I am using to write the data from a view into an excel spreadsheet using memorystream.  Currently, when the data is written from the memorystream to the excel file, the excel column widths are all the standard default widths.  Is there a way to modify these column header widths in the excel spreadsheet by keeping the current code structure/method and just adding to the code or slightly modifying the code?

```
public ActionResult ExportStudentRes()
    {
        //PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(vw_CheckList).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        Placeholder db = new PlaceholderEntities();

        List<vw_StudentResponse> studentres = db.vw_StudentResponse.ToList();

        PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(vw_StudentResponse).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            StringBuilder colHeading = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
            {
                colHeading.Append(prop.Name);
                colHeading.Append(",");
            }
            string cHeading = colHeading.ToString();
            cHeading = cHeading.TrimEnd(',');

            writer.Write(cHeading);
            writer.Write("\n");

            foreach (vw_StudentResponse item in studentres)
            {
                StringBuilder rowValues = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++)
                {

                    rowValues.Append(Props[i].GetValue(item));
                    rowValues.Append(",");
                }
                string rvalues = rowValues.ToString();
                rvalues = rvalues.TrimEnd(',');
                writer.Write(rvalues);
                writer.Write("\n");
            }
        }


        string downloadFileName = "export_StudentResponse.csv";

        string contentType = "text/csv";

        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = contentType;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + downloadFileName);
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ToArray());
        Response.End();

        return View();

    }
```

Comment: No, thats not an Excel file, its a plain-text CSV file that Excel happens to be able to open.  To control how Excel displays the data you would need to create a proper Excel XLS/X file.

Comment: I updated the question title to include CSV.  Okay, that makes sense and was what I was thinking, but just wanted to confirm.  So what you are saying is that I would have to implement a physical excel file somewhere to modify the column header widths when the data is opened in the excel file?

Comment: @SunSunKu exactly. It would need to be an XLS or XLSX file. A CSV is list a listing of values, no Excel formatting supported.

Comment: @SunSunKu gembox is a pretty good library for creating excel files.

Comment: @BillRuhl I have heard positive remarks about gembox and might be using gembox in the future or most likely will look into it.